# I Need Help Randomizing an <a> Tag

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I'm in the process of coding a random joke generator, and I was wondering how I could randomize the destination of an  tag. I have good JavaScript skills, but as a 12 year old, I'm new to HTML and CSS. I don't know if it matters, but I code on Replit.

My idea is that I have three buttons, each determining the type of joke to generate, and then each has an  tag that leads to a separate file with a joke. Currently, I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCEXu.png)

But of course, it only leads to *one* file, which means one joke, which means sad. I'm thinking that Javascript would be able to fix this, and I could maybe use a  tag to import it or something. If you can help, then thank you!

Comment: Hey @OhNoltsA8 - If you could include your code so far, and not as a screenshot (so we can run it), that would be helpful.

Comment: **Never** wrap other action elements like `button` inside an Anchor tag `a`. Instead,  **use CSS** to style your `a` as desired. I.e: create a class `.btn` and add it to any element you desire to look like.

Comment: @Lissy93 Here's a bit of my code:

<div class="container">
  <div class="vertical-center">
   
    <a href="darkjoke1.html">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">The Dark Side</button>
        </a>
   
    <a href="joke1.html">
    <button>The Light Side</button>
    </a>
     <a href="dumbjoke1.html">
    <button>The Dumb Side</button>
    </a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to break it down:

1. Define your list of possible destinations
2. Select one at random
3. Grab the DOM element to change
4. Set the DOM element's href link to your random page

Here's a working example:

```js
const destinations = [
  'my-destination-1.html',
  'my-destination-2.html',
  'my-destination-3.html',
  'my-destination-4.html',
  'my-destination-5.html'
];
 
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*destinations.length);

const randomDestination = destinations[randomIndex];

const randomJokeLink = document.getElementById('random-joke-link');

randomJokeLink.setAttribute("href", randomDestination);
```

```html
<a id="random-joke-link" href="#">Random Joke</a>
```